# How can I validate a table's data and <potentially> throw an error with BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a scheduled query called `doStuff` which runs daily and looks like this

```
select * from bleh.foo left join bleh.bar on foo.a = bar.a
```

How can I validate the data in `foo` before executing the query? For example, I may want to confirm that `foo` doesn't have duplicate values in column `a`, in which case I'd like to do something like this.

```
if duplicates_exist(a):
  raise exception "query failed because column 'a' contains dupes"
else:
  select * from bleh.foo left join bleh.bar on foo.a = bar.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you want to do :

```
if exists (select 1 from foo group by a having count(*) > 1) 
   raise exception "query failed because column 'a' contains dupes"
else
  select * from bleh.foo left join bleh.bar on foo.a = bar.a
```

Comment: My pseudocode turned out to be strikingly close to the actual syntax. (I didn't realize I could actually use if-else statements in BigQuery.) Seems like the relevant documentation I was searching for his [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if).